# executing raw sql in rails vs java

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am using raw mysql queries in my rails application. but the response time which i was getting while executing the same mysql queries in java was much better as i am getting in rails?

What are the bottleneck in running raw sql in rails as compared to java?

Answer (score 1):

Speed of the code being executed, including the database driver.

Ruby is regarded as slower to execute than Java. See [benchmarks like this](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/which-programs-are-fastest.html) (but take them as a rough guide)